# Insert statement in hive using cursor return -1

Tags: python, hive, cursor, impala

I am using impala.dbapi using python to insert data into Hive 2. The cursor.execute statement works fine and inserts data into the table.
But i am not able to get the rowcount that was inserted.

```
x = cursor.execute(insert_statement)
print(x)
print(cursor.rowcount)
```

Returns:-

```
None
-1
```

I want to identify how many rows got impacted.
Any suggestion?

Comment: After checking documentation i used print(cursor.rowcounts) but getting error Invalid method name GetRuntimeProfile

Comment: I think you need to remove `x=` and run it like this `cursor.execute(insert_statement)
print(cursor.rowcount)`. Outcome = -1 means its not executing. Not sure how data got into the table.

Comment: Not exactly, impala imementd one method rowcounts there is a jira for that. There for hive they parse the thrift op and returns affected rows and error rows. But i am now getting thrift error. Looks like its not going to the thrift class came with impala rather its going to the thrift package where there is no method call GetRuntimeProfile.